# Handling the Database Connection and network Issue in Catch Block

Tags: c#, oracle

```
private void ProcessInputQueueEntry(long parentNodeId, ExperianInputQueue eiq, UserInfo     uinf)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.InfoFormat("Processing InputQueue entry: {0}, Major: {1}, Minor:     {2}", eiq.Id, eiq.MajorType,
                                  eiq.MinorType);

                var parser = ExperianInputXMLParserFactory.Construct(eiq);
                // TODO: Try-catch + log the eiq ID + new status code for this eiq.
                switch (eiq.MajorType)
                {
                    case InputMajorType.ReportCases:
                        switch (eiq.MinorType)
                        {
                        case 1: // 1.1 -- Schema 2.1.1
                                CreateNewRegistration((ExperianReportCase)parser.GetObject(), parentNodeId, uinf);
                                break;
                            case 2: // 1.2 -- Schema 2.2.1
                                DeleteRegistration(parser, uinf);
                                break;
                            case 3: // 1.3 -- Schema 2.3.1
                                MoveToSolicitor(parser, parentNodeId, uinf);
                                break;
                            case 4: // 1.4 -- Schema 2.4.1
                                MoveToClient(parser, parentNodeId, uinf);
                                break;
                            case 5: // 1.5 -- Schema 2.5.1
                                Reopen(parser, parentNodeId, uinf);
                                break;
                            case 6: // 1.6 -- Schema 2.7.1
                                MoveToPublicService(parser, parentNodeId, uinf);
                                break;

                        }
                        break;
                    case InputMajorType.Cpr:
                        switch (eiq.MinorType)
                        {
                            case 1: // CPR: 2.1 
                                DeleteRegistrationsFromCpr(eiq.IdCardNo, uinf);
                                break;

                            //case 80: // CPR: 2.80 --UDR (The person has left Denmark)
                            //case 70: // CPR: 2.70 --FSV( The person has disappeared)
                            case 2: // CPR: UDR (Teh person has left Denmark)
                            case 3: // CPR: FSV( The person has disappeared) --UDB(The     person no longer has a permanent residence)
                            case 4: // CPR: UDB(The person no longer has a permanent     residence)
                            case 5:
                            case 6: // CPR: Call RKI
                            case 7:

                                try
                                {
                                    HandleCPRStatusUpdateOtherThanDeath(eiq.IdCardNo, uinf, eiq.MinorType);
                                }

                                catch (Exception exception)
                                {
                                    logger.ErrorFormat("An error occurred while updating     the cpr status for the InputQueue task for eiq ID = {0} -- stacktrace ---> {1}", eiq.Id,     exception);
                                    throw exception;
                                }

                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case InputMajorType.CustomerDeletion:
                        switch (eiq.MinorType)
                        {
                            case 1: // DeleteCustomer: 3.1
                                DeleteRegistrationsByCustomer(eiq.ExperianCustomerNumber, uinf);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case InputMajorType.IdCardCombined:

                        switch (eiq.MinorType)
                        {
                            case 1: // CombineIdCards: 4.1
                                CombineIdCards(parser, parentNodeId, uinf);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case InputMajorType.Document:

                        switch (eiq.MinorType)
                        {
                            case 1: // 5.1
                                AddDocumentToNode(parser, eiq.NodeId, eiq.Data, uinf);
                                break;
                            case 2: // Pass documents to a Feedback dossier node through     Upload Document.
                                AddDocumentToFeedbackDossierNode(parser, eiq.NodeId, uinf);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case InputMajorType.CustomerContractTerminated: //TTP1256
                        if (eiq.MinorType == 1)
                        {
                            HandleCustomerContractTermination(eiq.ExperianCustomerNumber, uinf);
                        }
                        break;
                        default:
                        break;
                }
                eiq.Status = 1; // Processed...
                UpdateInputQueueItem(eiq, uinf);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.ErrorFormat("Error while executing EsdhInputQueue task for eiq ID     = {0} -- stacktrace ---> {1}", eiq.Id, ex);
                eiq.Status = 0; // Status = ErrorProcessing! //#1131 Making the state to     0 if the failure is due to network or web service is down so that i can process next time
            //Added for 2134
                EventLog.WriteEntry("Task Scheduler", "An Error has occured while     processing the input queue case", EventLogEntryType.Error, 2);
                UpdateInputQueueItem(eiq, uinf);
            }
        }
```

My code is listed above....In the last catch block....I need to catch exception if there is any database connective issue or any network access issue (Like the data cannot be fetched or some issue with databse from the server side) and make the corresponding status as 1 so that it can be picked later for processing.How can I go about adding this as a if statement in the ending catch block.

Answer (score 1):

You need a catch for all the specific exceptions you are trying to catch, starting with the most specific to most general

```
try
{
 //Some Code
}
catch (CommunicationException ex)
{
//Do something
}
catch (AnotherException ex)
{
//Do something
}
```

Btw it is in general a bad idea to catch the base Exception class

Comment: What if I need to add any exception related to not able to fetch some files from the server as the server is busy ? Can I add a oracle exception in this case

Comment: @AnkitBansal If you have a base type for all these exceptions you can just use that

Answer (score 0):

In general , when we we deal with Exceptions, we must always start by the more specific one in our context to the more general one which is `Exception`.

```
try
{  
 //Your code
}
catch (OracleException orEx)
{
}
try
{  
 //Your code
}
catch (WebException wbEx)//if via web app
{
}
 try
{  
 //Your code
}
catch (SocketException skEx)//The exception that is thrown when a socket error occurs.
{
}
try
{  
 //Your code
}
catch (Exception Ex)//the more general exception
{
}
```

Comment: IS THERE ANY OTHER METHOD TO HANDLE THESE ISSUES...aAs these exception cannot be handled in .net version 3.5.... By if statement for checking if connection is not available....I tried adding Oracle exception namespace..It gives me a error... and same for socket exception namespace also.

Comment: Those are just examples. But in your case you can consult MSDN for .net 3.5 You have [OracleException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.oracleclient(v=vs.90).aspx) and [SocketException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception(v=vs.90).aspx) in .Net 3.5

Comment: Thanks for your comment on this...I realized one more problem here.How can i update the id column in the database if there is no connectivity  from the database (In case the oracle exception has occurred) .Will the id in my case get updated if I simply put oracle exception in the catch block.

Comment: How can I change the connection string of the oracle in the code at runtime to check whether my exception is being handled or not..

Comment: What you can do you access the object `OracleConnection.connection` and then you assign a `string` value like this `Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
Integrated Security=no;` [source](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)